# How to declare compare function in header

Tags: c++, class, header-files, bsearch, sortcomparefunction

**I have written compare function for bsearch in c++ class file**

```
int comp(const void* keyBases, const void* offset) {

    myStruct pi = *(myStruct*) keyBases;
    const void* stringInFile = (char*)pi.first + *((int*)offset);
    const void* searchString = pi.second;


    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        char firstsChar = *((char*) searchString + i);
        char secondsChar = *((char*) stringInFile + i);
        toLowerCase(firstsChar); toLowerCase(secondsChar);
        if (firstsChar < secondsChar) return -1;
        if (firstsChar > secondsChar) return 1;
        if (firstsChar == 0 && secondsChar == 0) return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**how to declare it in header file? Is static keyword needed?**

Comment: Do you really mean *define* or do you mean *declare*? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? *Why* do you want to "define" the function in a header file?

Comment: THis is certainly an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes declare maybe, I want to declare functions in header file and write some comments about them there. I want it in private section, but is static keyword needed or something like that?

Comment: Consider using [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with some [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and/or some standard [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). Explain what your real problem is and motivate your question. So **edit your question** to improve it a lot. Add some [MCVE], and several paragraphs about your application, work context, and motivation

Comment: Don't use the old C library when you have algorithms. Use std::lower_bound!

Answer (score 1):

A function *declaration* (also known as a function *prototype*) is just the function header without its body, terminated by a semi-colon. It tells the compiler the return type, the name of the function, and the number and types of arguments.

In your case it would simply be

```
int comp(const void* keyBases, const void* offset);
```

Since it's just a declaration it can be anywhere in the same scope as the definition, and you can even have multiple (non-conflicting!) declarations in the same [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

You should only use the `static` keyword if you *define* the function (with its full body) in a header file. Or if you define the function as `static` in a source file (technically in a translation unit), and want a *forward declaration* of it.

Comment: Also, the OP could define some `static inline` function in a header file.